# Selenium not retrieving heading tag

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I have a function for testing credentials and for some reason it retrieves everything correct (the other elements) expect one tag, and I cant figure out why.

HTML :

```
<h6>
<font class="textFuchsia" id="errorMessage">This email does not exist in our system, please enter the email that was used for your registration</font>
</h6>
```

This is the section where Im checking for equality

```
@Test(priority = 2)
@Description(".")
public void LoginWithBadEmailTest() throws InterruptedException {

    loginPage.login(getProperty("email.unregistered"),getProperty("credentials.password"));

    assertEquals(loginPage.getErrorMessageLabel().getText(),getProperty("message.nonexisting.email"));
}
```

This is how Im getting the tag

```
@FindBy(id="errorMessage")
private Label errorMessageLabel;
```

I've also tried getting the exact xpath
The results Im getting (**loginPage.getErrorMessageLabel())**

> "Login components.Label$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4848b753@4d518b32"

If Im attaching .getText() the results are null..

The problem is that this headings shows only when inserting invalid email , and if the user inserted wrong password then he gets a different message but they both share the same ID.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using explicit wait for visibility of element?

Comment: Great idea ! I fixed it using Thread.sleep() . Thank you !!

Comment: Cool you can use explicit as it standard practice. Thread.sleep() is not a good practice